# gradle EAR plugin ignores ear block content when built through eclipse

Tags: gradle, eclipse-wtp, buildship

I’m adding custom attributes to MANIFEST.MF file and deplomentDescriptor in ear. whichworks as expected when we build via gradle cli, but when I deploy to a server in eclipse it dosen’t generate or deploy the MANIFEST.MF and application.xml files.

Gradle Version:6.5.1

ear module DIR structure

sampleEAR

```
--META-INF
    -MANIFEST.MF
    -application.xml
--build.gradle
--settings.gradle
```

sampleEAR build.gradle file

step-1: referring to META-INF dir

```
plugins {
    id 'ear'
    id 'eclipse-wtp'
}
description = "Sample Application"

dependencies{
    deploy fileTree(dir: "../SampleEAR", include: 'core*.jar')
    deploy project(path: ':SampleWeb', configuration: 'archives')
    deploy project(':SampleService')
    earlib project(':SampleModel')
}

ear {
    metaInf {
        from 'META-INF'
        exclude 'MANIFEST.MF'
    }
    manifest {
        attributes('Created-By': "Gradle $gradle.gradleVersion",
             'version': archiveVersion,
          'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
         )
    }
}
```

step-2: generate application.xml via gradle

```
ear {
    deploymentDescriptor {
        applicationName = 'Sample'
        description = "Generated by Gradle $gradle.gradleVersion"
        displayName = project.name
        webModule("SampleWeb.war", 'Sample')
    }
    manifest {
        attributes('Created-By': "Gradle $gradle.gradleVersion",
            'version': archiveVersion,
            'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
        )
    }
}
```

step-3:

```
ear {
    from("META-INF"){
        into("META-INF")
    }
    generateDeploymentDescriptor = false
    manifest {
        attributes('Created-By': "Gradle $gradle.gradleVersion",
            'version': archiveVersion,
            'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
        )
    }
}
```

I have tried above 3 steps and it works fine via cli, but not with eclipse IDE.

When deployed to a server in eclipse, it would not create a META-INF content. I need the META-INF content from the src to be deployed via eclipse into ear and deploy if customized via manifest attirbutes or deplomentDescriptor.

Thanks,
Karthik